# "My Articles' Comments" or "My Article Comments" | "My Reviews' Comments" or "My Review Comments"

Tags: grammatical-number, possessives

I need to add menu items (filters) on my website but I'm not sure which one is correct:

- My Articles' Comments
- My Reviews' Comments

OR

- My Article Comments
- My Review Comments

For example, if you click on "*My Review Comments*" (or "*My Reviews' Comments*") - it will display all of your comments on the reviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those titles have different meanings.

"My Articles'/Reviews' Comments" should show all comments, made by any user, on your articles and your reviews.

"My Article/Review Comments" should show all comments, made by you, on an article or review made by any user.

The key point here is that in "My Article/Review Comments," *Article* or *Review* are adjectives (or *noun adjuncts*, if you prefer), so the determiner *my* modifies the noun, *Comments.*  In other words, it's the comments that belong to you.

In "My Articles'/Reveiws' Comments," *Articles'* or *Reviews'* are nouns, so the *my* modifies them, and it's the articles or reviews that belong to you.